# Access method in viewcontroller from appdelegate

Tags: iphone, function, sdk, uiviewcontroller

I want to use appdelegate for applicationDidBecomeActive and I want this function to use method which is placed in viewcontroller. How I am gonna do that?
The only thing that I find is to access from anywhere the appdelegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your *applicationDelegate* class a reference to the *viewController* that you want to call the method on. You could do this by creating an instance variable or a property of the *applicationDelegate* that points to your *viewController* that you want to be able to call the method on. If you create your viewController in the init method of your *appDelegate*, or in your `applicationDidLoad:` method, then you can simply assign this *viewController* to the instance variable/property that you've created.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the root view controller of your app from within the app delegate through the window property, that is `self.window.rootViewController`. The view controller that you want to access must be a child of the root view controller or at least accessible through it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of needing to call a method on my view controller from the app delegate.  After some digging and reading this answer I tried to call a method (saveData was the method in question) in my view controller directly from the app delegate and it worked as required.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {[self.window addSubview:rootViewController_iPad.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}


        -(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        [rootViewController_iPad saveData];
    }
```

Hope this helps.